# Discuss with *name* on the friday skype vs on a friday skype

Tags: questions

Is it correct to say: "Dont' forget to discuss `*X*` with `*NAME*` on the friday skype" or "Dont' forget to discuss `*X*` with `*NAME*` on a friday skype"?

Comment: If your counterpart understands *skype* as contraction of *skype call* sure. The definite versus indefinite article depends, are you referring to a specific Friday, use *the*, if not, use *a*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If this is an established call that's been set up, the first one is good. Otherwise I might go with "Don't forget to discuss `*X*` with `*NAME*` on Skype on Friday", or "over Skype on Friday", or "on Friday over Skype"

Answer (score 0):

Driven by "definite" or "indefinite" articles I would suggest that:

"The Friday Skpye" refers to the next one in chronological order, while

"A Friday Skype" refers to bringing the topic up at some future point, but not necessarily the next one.